# Cocoapods - Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox, mapbox-ios, .netrc

I want to install last version of Mapbox with Cocoapods.
I configure `.netrc` file :

```
machine api.mapbox.com 
login mapbox
password <MY_SECRET_TOKEN>
```

But when I launch `pod install`, I have this error :

```
[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/vq/jpt1fhxd6fx58rz9zvbdtw000000gn/T/d20200922-35020-qeu6k2/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.2.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0    44    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401
```

How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 44):

It took a night for me. After googling too many hours i can't find the best solution to write the secret key on `.netrc` file. Please follow the procedure:

1. Go to Terminal and write **cd ~**
2. Press Enter.
3. Write **vi .netrc**  . It will open the empty file in the terminal.
4. Press **i** here to insert data here. When you enter **i** it will open in insert mode.
5. Now paste

```
    machine api.mapbox.com
    login mapbox
    password sk.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Note:** Don't put `<` braces in password `>`

6. Press **Esc** Key from keyboard.
7. Write **:w** to write all data on file.
8. Now write **:q** to quit from file.
9. You successfully save the file.
10. Run Pod install

Comment: why so complicated open open .netrc

Answer (score 13):

Please make sure that you have saved the `.netrc` file in your computer's home directory (not the project's home directory) and that you have pasted your secret token (a new token with the `Downloads:Read` scope) into the file.

Comment: My problem came from the hooks "<>". Thanks.

Comment: In my case Downloads:Read scope was the issue!

Answer (score 8):

That part of the guide might be a bit confusing.

In my case, I realised that the file `.netrc` was already in my Home directory. I just had to open a new Terminal and do `nano .netrc`. Then I added those 3 lines:

```
machine api.mapbox.com
  login mapbox
  password PRIVATE_MAPBOX_API_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 7):

I searched for fix it so much. but at the end I found the easiest way.
You Have to just install lower version instead of 6.3.0

I fixed the issue with version : 4.11.2

and edit your Podfile Like this :

```
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.11.2'
```

Comment: guess using older versions is not a right option.

Comment: This wont work for M1 Macs.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your 'Create token' in https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens, do remember to check the `Downloads:Read` scope.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This work fo me**

1. open terminal
2. cd ~ (go to the home directory)
3. touch .netrc (create a file)
4. open .netrc (open file)
5. add require data
6. save file  (cmd + s)

5. require data must be like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(MAC system) I spent hours on this error and at the end I saw that the `.netrc file` is actually written as a `netrc file` (without the dot), so even if you rename it, it doesn't work, you have to create the file from terminal, using:

- vi .netrc
- mode insert
- paste

> ```
> machine <name>
> login <user>> 
> password <token>
> ```

- esc
- :x

Now with `pod repo-art add repoName url` you can connect success

Answer (score 0):

Open the Pod file of your project and remove pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK' and save it and close it . And run `pod install` and `pod clean` in your terminal and go back to Pod file of your project again and re-write  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK' and on your terminal run `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

A comprehensive answer that worked for me:

1. make sure your token has `DOWNLOADS:READ` scope
2. vi ~/.netrc and insert the following lines :

> ```
>     machine api.mapbox.com
>     login mapbox
>     password whatever_token_we_have
> ```

3. voilà